# Subquery returned more than 1 value in temp table stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, temp-tables

When I execute my stored procedure it shows the this error

> 'Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression'.  How to solve this?

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPEMPIDDETAILS]
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @INTSTART AS INTEGER;
    DECLARE @INTSTOP AS INTEGER;

    DECLARE @PREFNO AS VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE @PVAL AS DATE;

    DECLARE @VREFNO AS VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE @VVAL AS DATE;

    DECLARE @SBREFNO AS VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE @SBVAL AS VARCHAR(50);

    DECLARE @UVREFNO AS VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE @UVVAL AS DATE;

    DECLARE @TEMPTABLEEMP TABLE (PREFNO VARCHAR(50),
                                 PVAL DATE, VREFNO VARCHAR(50),
                                 VVAL DATE, SBREFNO VARCHAR(50),
                                 SBVAL DATE, UVREFNO VARCHAR(50), UVVAL DATE)

    SELECT @INTSTART = 1;
    SELECT @INTSTOP = (SELECT COUNT(PK_ID) FROM EMPIDDETAILS);

    WHILE @INTSTART <= @INTSTOP
    BEGIN
        SELECT 
            @PREFNO = (SELECT REF_NO FROM EMPIDDETAILS  
                       WHERE DOCUMENT_TYPE = 'PASSPORT'),
            @PVAL = (SELECT VALIDITY FROM EMPIDDETAILS 
                     WHERE DOCUMENT_TYPE = 'PASSPORT')
        --GROUP BY EMPIDDETAILS.EMPLOYE

        SELECT 
            @VREFNO = (SELECT REF_NO FROM EMPIDDETAILS 
                       WHERE DOCUMENT_TYPE = 'VISA'),
            @VVAL = (SELECT VALIDITY FROM EMPIDDETAILS 
                     WHERE DOCUMENT_TYPE = 'VISA')

        SELECT 
            @SBREFNO = (SELECT REF_NO FROM EMPIDDETAILS 
                        WHERE DOCUMENT_TYPE = 'SEAMAN BOOK'),
            @SBVAL = (SELECT VALIDITY FROM EMPIDDETAILS 
                      WHERE DOCUMENT_TYPE = 'SEAMAN BOOK')

        SELECT 
            @UVREFNO = (SELECT REF_NO FROM EMPIDDETAILS 
                        WHERE DOCUMENT_TYPE = 'USVISA'),
            @UVVAL = (SELECT VALIDITY FROM EMPIDDETAILS 
                      WHERE DOCUMENT_TYPE = 'USVISA')

        INSERT INTO @TEMPTABLEEMP 
        VALUES(@PREFNO, @PVAL, @VREFNO, @VVAL, @SBREFNO, @SBVAL, @UVREFNO, @UVVAL)

        SET @PREFNO = 0
        SET @PVAL = NULL
        SET @VREFNO = 0
        SET @VVAL = NULL
        SET @SBREFNO = 0
        SET @SBVAL = NULL
        SET @UVREFNO = 0
        SET @UVVAL = NULL

        SET @INTSTART = @INTSTART + 1;
    END

    SELECT 
        PREFNO, PVAL, VREFNO, VVAL, SBREFNO, SBVAL, UVREFNO, UVVAL 
    FROM @TEMPTABLEEMP
END
```

Comment: `SELECT @PREFNO=(...,  SELECT @VREFNO=(... ,  SELECT @SBREFNO=(...,  SELECT @UVREFNO=(...` Make sure these queries return only one row

Comment: You forgot to filter by `EMP_ID` (`PK_ID` in your table I guess)

Comment: or at least use `DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything about your data, it's hard to say, but you try assign query results to values. What if query e.g.

```
SELECT @PREFNO=(SELECT REF_NO FROM EMPIDDETAILS WHERE DOCUMENT_TYPE='PASSPORT')
```

returns more than one document type passport? This can be applied to all your queries where you wanted to store value in variable.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning values to variables using select statement. Some time there might be multiple records exist based on your filter. Please check your Document_Type filter one of our filter returning more than one value. In order to avoid this you can use "Top 1"

Refer This,

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPEMPIDDETAILS]
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @INTSTART AS INTEGER;
    DECLARE @INTSTOP AS INTEGER;
    DECLARE @PREFNO AS VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE @PVAL AS DATE;
    DECLARE @VREFNO AS VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE @VVAL AS DATE;
    DECLARE @SBREFNO AS VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE @SBVAL AS VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE @UVREFNO AS VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE @UVVAL AS DATE;
    DECLARE @TEMPTABLEEMP TABLE (
        PREFNO VARCHAR(50)
        ,PVAL DATE
        ,VREFNO VARCHAR(50)
        ,VVAL DATE
        ,SBREFNO VARCHAR(50)
        ,SBVAL DATE
        ,UVREFNO VARCHAR(50)
        ,UVVAL DATE
        )

    SELECT @INTSTART = 1;

    SELECT @INTSTOP = (
            SELECT COUNT(PK_ID)
            FROM EMPIDDETAILS
            );

    WHILE @INTSTART <= @INTSTOP
    BEGIN
        SELECT @PREFNO = (
                SELECT TOP 1 REF_NO
                FROM EMPIDDETAILS
                WHERE DOCUMENT_TYPE = 'PASSPORT'
                )
            ,@PVAL = (
                SELECT TOP 1 VALIDITY
                FROM EMPIDDETAILS
                WHERE DOCUMENT_TYPE = 'PASSPORT'
                )

        --GROUP BY EMPIDDETAILS.EMPLOYE
        SELECT @VREFNO = (
                SELECT TOP 1 REF_NO
                FROM EMPIDDETAILS
                WHERE DOCUMENT_TYPE = 'VISA'
                )
            ,@VVAL = (
                SELECT TOP 1 VALIDITY
                FROM EMPIDDETAILS
                WHERE DOCUMENT_TYPE = 'VISA'
                )

        SELECT @SBREFNO = (
                SELECT TOP 1 REF_NO
                FROM EMPIDDETAILS
                WHERE DOCUMENT_TYPE = 'SEAMAN BOOK'
                )
            ,@SBVAL = (
                SELECT TOP 1 VALIDITY
                FROM EMPIDDETAILS
                WHERE DOCUMENT_TYPE = 'SEAMAN BOOK'
                )

        SELECT @UVREFNO = (
                SELECT TOP 1 REF_NO
                FROM EMPIDDETAILS
                WHERE DOCUMENT_TYPE = 'USVISA'
                )
            ,@UVVAL = (
                SELECT TOP 1 VALIDITY
                FROM EMPIDDETAILS
                WHERE DOCUMENT_TYPE = 'USVISA'
                )

        INSERT INTO @TEMPTABLEEMP
        VALUES (
            @PREFNO
            ,@PVAL
            ,@VREFNO
            ,@VVAL
            ,@SBREFNO
            ,@SBVAL
            ,@UVREFNO
            ,@UVVAL
            )

        SET @PREFNO = 0
        SET @PVAL = NULL
        SET @VREFNO = 0
        SET @VVAL = NULL
        SET @SBREFNO = 0
        SET @SBVAL = NULL
        SET @UVREFNO = 0
        SET @UVVAL = NULL
        SET @INTSTART = @INTSTART + 1;
    END

    SELECT PREFNO
        ,PVAL
        ,VREFNO
        ,VVAL
        ,SBREFNO
        ,SBVAL
        ,UVREFNO
        ,UVVAL
    FROM @TEMPTABLEEMP
END
```

Comment: top 1 without order by is usually a mistake, as there is no way to guarantee what record would be returned.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do is to add a TOP(1) clause to all the sub queries used to assign to variable

Comment: Actually, that's not really the best thing to do. top 1 without order by is usually a mistake, as there is no way to guarantee what record would be returned.

Answer (score 0):

There are some tables where your data has duplicate values. for example in the line

```
SELECT @PREFNO=(SELECT REF_NO FROM EMPIDDETAILS WHERE DOCUMENT_TYPE='PASSPORT'),@PVAL=(SELECT VALIDITY FROM EMPIDDETAILS WHERE DOCUMENT_TYPE='PASSPORT')
```

When you say `SELECT REF_NO FROM EMPIDDETAILS WHERE DOCUMENT_TYPE='PASSPORT'` there might be some cases where there are two `REF_NO` that has the same `DOCUMENT_TYPE` thus giving you two results.

In order to avoid this, either you have to add another condition where you can say that it has no duplicate values (perhaps a **primary key**) or add `TOP 1` in order to ensure that the query returns only one data.

```
SELECT @PREFNO=(SELECT TOP 1 REF_NO FROM EMPIDDETAILS WHERE DOCUMENT_TYPE='PASSPORT'),@PVAL=(SELECT TOP 1 VALIDITY FROM EMPIDDETAILS WHERE DOCUMENT_TYPE='PASSPORT')
```

Now there are times that the data returned from the query is not the data you expected. So you might consider adding an `ORDER BY`  clause so that the very first data the is fetched from the query is the desired data you want.

EXAMPLE :

```
SELECT @PREFNO=(SELECT TOP 1 REF_NO FROM EMPIDDETAILS WHERE DOCUMENT_TYPE='PASSPORT' ORDER BY pk_id DESC)
```

The example above just retrieves the `REF_NO` has the highest `pk_id` considering that `pk_id` is a `primary key` with an `INT` data type.

**UPDATE**: another thing is just to add `DISTINCT` if data with the same `DOCUMENT_TYPE` is entirely the same.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no need for cursor. Take a look at two approaches with same output. Your major problem was that you declared `@INTSTART` as ID of EMP but did not use it in filters.

```
DECLARE @EMPIDDETAILS TABLE 
(
    PK_ID INT NOT NULL,
    REF_NO VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    DOCUMENT_TYPE VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    VALIDITY BIT NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO @EMPIDDETAILS (PK_ID, REF_NO, DOCUMENT_TYPE, VALIDITY)
VALUES
(1, '111-VISA', 'VISA', 1),
(1, '111-PASS', 'PASSPORT', 1),
(2, '222-PASS', 'PASSPORT', 0),
(2, '222-SEEA', 'SEAMAN BOOK', 1),
(2, '222-VISA', 'VISA', 1),
(2, '222-USVS', 'USVISA', 0)


SELECT
    ed.PK_ID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN ed.DOCUMENT_TYPE = 'PASSPORT' THEN ed.REF_NO END) AS PREFNO,
    MAX(CASE WHEN ed.DOCUMENT_TYPE = 'PASSPORT' THEN CAST(ed.VALIDITY AS INT) END) AS PVAL, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN ed.DOCUMENT_TYPE = 'VISA' THEN ed.REF_NO END) AS VREFNO,
    MAX(CASE WHEN ed.DOCUMENT_TYPE = 'VISA' THEN CAST(ed.VALIDITY AS INT) END) AS VVAL, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN ed.DOCUMENT_TYPE = 'SEAMAN BOOK' THEN ed.REF_NO END) AS SBREFNO,
    MAX(CASE WHEN ed.DOCUMENT_TYPE = 'SEAMAN BOOK' THEN CAST(ed.VALIDITY AS INT) END) AS SBVAL, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN ed.DOCUMENT_TYPE = 'USVISA' THEN ed.REF_NO END) AS UVREFNO,
    MAX(CASE WHEN ed.DOCUMENT_TYPE = 'USVISA' THEN CAST(ed.VALIDITY AS INT) END) AS UVVAL 
FROM @EMPIDDETAILS ed 
GROUP BY ed.PK_ID


SELECT
    pv.PK_ID,
    MAX([PASSPORT]) AS [PASSPORT],
    MAX([PASSPORT-VALIDITY]) AS [PASSPORT-VALIDITY], 
    MAX([VISA]) AS [VISA],
    MAX([VISA-VALIDITY]) AS [VISA-VALIDITY], 
    MAX([SEAMAN BOOK]) AS [SEAMAN BOOK],
    MAX([SEAMAN BOOK-VALIDITY]) AS [SEAMAN BOOK-VALIDITY], 
    MAX([USVISA]) AS [USVISA],
    MAX([USVISA-VALIDITY]) AS [USVISA-VALIDITY] 
FROM 
(
    SELECT
        ed.PK_ID, ed.REF_NO, ed.DOCUMENT_TYPE,
        CAST(ed.VALIDITY AS INT) AS VALIDITY,
        ed.DOCUMENT_TYPE+'-VALIDITY' as REF_VAL 
    FROM @EMPIDDETAILS ed
) ed
PIVOT
(
    MAX(ed.REF_NO)
    FOR ed.DOCUMENT_TYPE IN ([VISA], [PASSPORT], [SEAMAN BOOK], [USVISA])
) pr
PIVOT
(
    MAX(pr.VALIDITY)
    FOR pr.REF_VAL IN ([VISA-VALIDITY], [PASSPORT-VALIDITY], [SEAMAN BOOK-VALIDITY], [USVISA-VALIDITY])
) pv
GROUP BY pv.PK_ID
```

In the end just insert into your temptable or do whatever you want.

[image]